# Pass image in listview click with intent putExtras

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to figure out how to add an image as an extra for an Intent using putExtra, so i can then get in in another activity

im stuggling here because im not sure what goes after my drawable:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
          // When clicked, bring up MockSchool.class
      if(position == 1)
      {
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MockSchool.class);
          myIntent.putExtra(R.drawable.mydrawable,  );
          startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your drawable is in fact value, while the key is some arbitrary string. For eg.

```
myIntent.putExtra("myDrawable", R.drawable.mydrawable)
```

Just be sure to use the same string when retrieving resource:

```
  myIntent.getIntExtra("myDrawable");
```

Comment: when retreiving the resource "myDrawable" do i have to create a whole new intent in that activity?

Comment: of course not. in your new activity just use getIntent().getIntExtra("myDrawable");

Comment: This will set the resource int that refers to the drawable to the intent - not the actual drawable. Not saying it's wrong (in fact preferable where applicable) but good to know.